Compare two variances
I am reading this paper
I have difficulty understanding Section 6: A Linear Time Statistic and Test.
At the beginning, they claim that $\text{MMD}^2_l$ has higher variance than $\text{MMD}^2_u$ (we will see this explicitly later).' However, I don’t understand the reason, even after reading the remaining part
I guess it comes from those lines

Assume $0 < \mathbb{E}(h^2) < \infty$. Then $\text{MMD}_l^2$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian according to
$$m^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \text{MMD}_l^2 - \text{MMD}^2[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \right) \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_l^2)$$
where
$$
\sigma_l^2 = 2 \left[ \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h^2(z, z') - \left( \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right]$$
where we use the shorthand $\mathbb{E}_{z, z'} := \mathbb{E}_{z, z' \sim p \times q}$
The factor of 2 arises since we are averaging over only $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor$ observations. It is instructive to compare this asymptotic distribution with that of the quadratic time statistic $\text{MMD}_u^2$ under $\mathcal{H}_A$, when $m = n$. In this case, $\text{MMD}_u^2$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian according to
$$m^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \text{MMD}_u^2 - \text{MMD}^2[\mathcal{F}, p, q] \right) \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_u^2)$$
where
$$
\sigma_u^2 = 4 \left( \mathbb{E}_z \left[ \left( \mathbb{E}_{z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right] - \left( \mathbb{E}_{z, z'} h(z, z') \right)^2 \right) \quad \text{(Serfling, 1980, Section 5.5)}.$$
Thus for $\text{MMD}_u^2$, the asymptotic variance is (up to scaling) the variance of $\mathbb{E}_z[h(z, z')]$, whereas for $\text{MMD}_l^2$ it is $\text{Var}_{z, z'}[h(z, z')]$

I am quite confused about how they can prove their statement. I hope you can explain it to me explicitly because I am relatively new to this field. Many thanks.

This is a consequence of the Law of Total Variance:
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]).$$
In this case,
$$\operatorname{Var}_{z, z'}[h(z, z')] = \underbrace{\operatorname{E}_{z}[\operatorname{Var}_{z'}(h(z, z'))]}_{\geq 0 }+ \operatorname{Var}_z(\operatorname{E}_{z'}[h(z, z')]) \geq \operatorname{Var}_z(\operatorname{E}_{z'}[h(z, z')]), $$
as the term $\operatorname{E}_{z}[\operatorname{Var}_{z'}(h(z, z'))]$ is non-negative.

But how about the number $2$ and $4$ before them?

I think they're ignoring those leading constants when they say "(up to scaling)"?
It also seems like the original claim in the paper is weaker, only that "it is expected that $\text{MMD}^2_l$ has higher variance than $\text{MMD}^2_u$ (as we will see explicitly later)". You can probably find $h,p,q$ where one statistic has larger asymptotic variance than the other and vice versa.
